# What does 80::80 mean?

Tags: ip

I was trying to connect to a router and the IP address for that device had and IP address with 80::80 at the end of it.I just wanted to know what it was and in what scenarios it would be used?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation). `::` is replaced by an appropriate number of zeroes (it's a shorthand notation).